# Jquery Tablesorter&Tabs - show form after clicking button

Tags: tablesorter, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a table using Jquery TableSorter in combination with Jquery UI TABS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsvyX.png

(Sry can't post images since I need 10 reputation)

What I want is when I click on "Ändern" (which means change (German)), I want the table to disappear and instead a form to be shown. **(Tabs shall stay)**

I tried:

```js
function aendern(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "aendern.php?vorgang=aendern&geraeteID=" + id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){     
            $("#domainsTable5").html(data);
    
      },
                   dataType: 'html'
                });
            }
```

Which opens the form, the table is gone, but it turns black: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KAfF.png

This is my button:

```html
echo '<button onclick="aendern(' . $id . ')">Ändern</button>';
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Was this you](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/871)? Did you find your solution?